# FacebookSDK 3.0 - Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, api

I am trying to implement Facebook in one of my apps and therefore followed the official Facebook Tutorial on Hackbook. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/

I implemented everything as described and I don't get any error or warnings. However when I try to build the app, I get 17 Mach-O Linker Errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_FBSessionStateChangedNotification", referenced from:
      -[ForeverMainViewController sessionStateChanged:state:error:] in ForeverMainViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      ___23-[FBCacheIndex dealloc]_block_invoke_0 in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      _releaseStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      _initializeStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      ___36-[FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke_0 in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      _releaseStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
      ___36-[FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke_0 in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      _initializeStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
      _initializeStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _dropTrimmingTable] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

After reimplementing, cleaning the app, making sure everything was there, I am out of ideas. I also implemented it in another app, but good the errors again. The given samples from Facebook however work as intended. I did various tipps on the internet, but none of them worked so far. Maybe someone here knows something about the API and has a good tip for me :)

Comment: Have you tried building for the device (iPhone/iPad,..) as well? Are there different error messages when trying that? Right now it looks a bit as if you are trying to link a simulator build against a device library.

Comment: Hey, I tried it with the iphone and ipad simulator and also on my device, but the error stays the same.

Comment: Ok, then ... are you sure that you followed the instructions on linking against the SDK (which should be included in that framework)?

Comment: Just to be sure I will do it _again_. But yes, I am 99.9% sure!

Comment: The error shouldn't stay the same.  The architecture at the bottom of the error should fail with `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7` if it did.

Comment: That is correct. I meant the errors I posted.

Comment: Is it possible you aren't `#import`'ing this framework in the files it mentions?

Comment: Just to be safe I imported in the delegate and in the view controller. But that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you are missing this line

NSString *const FBSessionStateChangedNotification = @"FBSessionStateChangedNotification";

and adding reference to -lsqlite3.0

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/getting-started-with-the-ios-sdk/#project

Comment: Thank you, I actually forgot the reference. Silly me :D

Comment: You’ll get linker errors (duplicate symbols for me with the 3.0 SDK) if you add `NSString *const FBSessionStateChangedNotification = @"FBSessionStateChangedNotification”;`, but thanks for pointing to sqlite3.0! Totally missed that section in the project setup.

Comment: make sure you add it to the target build settings, just adding it to the project build settings didn't work for me.

Comment: Can someone tell me why do we need to add reference to -lsqlite3.0? I don't see any details given in the documentation

Answer (score 4):

I think your are missing this

Goto Project->BuildPhase->Link Binary-Add->-lsqlite3.0

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I found the Solution : `libsqlite3.dylib` that i used compiled for armv6 not 7 , so you download Xcode dmg file (more then 4.2)and extract the lib from it .